# Code Signing: Missing DEVELOPER_DIR path

Tags: macos, code-signing

I'm using the `codesign` command line utility to sign an Atom Electron .app folder. The command I use is:

```
codesign --verbose --deep --force --sign "Mac Developer: <MY NAME AND IDENTIFIER HERE>" AdminTool.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework
```

I read that with Yosemite, the `codesign` utility requires that you manually sign each framework before you can sign the entire .app folder, so that's what I'm trying to do by signing just `Squirrel.framework` for now.

I get this error:

```
xcrun: error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun/

AdminTool.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```

I looked at a previous StackOverflow thread regarding the `codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found` issue and I followed what it said by reassigning the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable to the path in the `xcrun` error. I'm not sure if I messed something up and now cannot sign my app as a result.

Any help and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Ended up fixing this by installing the xcode command line tools with `xcode-select --install` and then running:

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developers
```

I assume this correctly reset my DEVELOPER_DIR path so that `codesign` could find it when I ran it again.